# Distribution of sum of cubes

Tags: normal-distribution

If a set of $k$ random variables $x$ is drawn from the same normal distribution with mean $μ$ and standard deviation $σ$, then:

- the mean of the distribution of $Σx$ is $kμ$
- the mean of the distribution of $Σx²$ is $k(μ²+σ²)$

Is there a similar closed-form expression for the mean of the distribution of $Σx³$ ?

Sorry if I've got the terminology wrong!

Comment: Technically you should mention that the observations are i.i.d. check out the  proposed duplicate that Patrick suggests.

Comment: The first answer gives you one way to arrive at the result except that 1 is plugged in for the mean & 2 for the standard deviation. The second answer gives you the way to solve it generally using moment generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then we can agree that 
\begin{align*}
   \text{E}[X] & = \mu\,,\\
   \text{E}[X^2] & = \mu^2+\sigma^2\,,\\
   \text{E}[(X-\mu)^3] & = 0\,,
\end{align*}
the last because the distribution of $X$ is symmetrical around 0. Now,
\begin{align*}
   0 & = \text{E}[(X-\mu)^3] = \text{E}[X^3-3\mu X^2+3\mu^3X-\mu^3] \\
     & = \text{E}[X^3] -3\mu \text{E}[X^2] + 3\mu^3-\mu^3 \\
     & = \text{E}[X^3] -3\mu(\mu^2+\sigma^2)+2\mu^3
       = \text{E}[X^3] -\mu^3-3\mu\sigma^2
\end{align*}
which means that $\text{E}[X^3] = \mu^3+\mu\sigma^2$. If $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,k$ are all $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then
$$
  \text{E}[\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^3]  = k(\mu^3+\mu\sigma^2)
$$
You could easily extend this to 4th moment, 5th moment and so on, using the fact that for even $n$:
$$
  \text{E}[(X-\mu)^n] = \sigma^n (n-1)(n-3)(n-5)\cdot\ldots\cdot1
$$

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I was looking for. Many thanks for taking the time to answer.